# Use a macro variable to when saving to a permanent SAS data set

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Trying to save data set `Keepmerge` as a permanent SAS data set called `Oct15Tot` using the code below.  If I sub `"&OutTabTot"` for just `Oct15Tot`, it works.  Trying to save myself from having to chang another bit of code further down (the `%let` is referenced at the beginning, and is used throughout my program.  Thanks!

```
%let OutTabTot = Oct15Tot;

libname WorkItem "\\WRKGRP\CVOWB\SAS Data Sets";
data WorkItem."&OutTabTot";
  set work.Keepmerge;
run;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
     22
      201
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, /, ;,
              _DATA_, _LAST_, _NULL_.

ERROR 201-322: The option is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the quotes in your Data statement it should work, like so:

```
%let OutTabTot = Oct15Tot;

libname WorkItem "\\WRKGRP\CVOWB\SAS Data Sets";

Data WorkItem.&OutTabTot;
   Set Work.Keepmerge;
Run;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, as cherry notes, you should just skip the quotations.

However, if you have *reason* to use quotations, you need to use an `n` afterwards to tell SAS to make this a name literal.

```
%let OutTabTot = Oct15 Tot;

options validmemname=extend;

libname WorkItem "\\WRKGRP\CVOWB\SAS Data Sets";
Data WorkItem."&OutTabTot"n;
Set Work.Keepmerge;
Run;
```

I don't recommend using things like dataset names with spaces if you can avoid it, as it's a pain... but it's legal, with [`options validmemname=extend`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/64892/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n10nwm6blrcrtmn0zdcwyxlwxfjh.htm) set.